# Implementation of iToast in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have seen this link and i came to know the usage of iToast [the link which i have seen about iToast](http://code.google.com/p/toast-notifications-ios/). But I didn't anywhere how to integrate it in iPhone application.Kindly tell me the way how to approach it.
                                    Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/toast-notifications-ios/wiki/HowToUse)

Comment: Just now I have seen that one. It is good. Thank you very much.

Comment: It was the next tab in the link you provided.